# upgrade manager malfunction

Tags: 12.04, update-manager, partial-upgrade

My upgrade manager won't upgrade anymore. Even the partial upgrade isn't working due to an unresolvable problem. I was thinking I would upgrade to the next version but I am unsure how to go about it. Should I just re-install ubuntu?? I am an ubuntu newbie. Thanks for any help out there

Answer (score 0):

Try doing upgrade via terminal

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo do-release-upgrade
```